# Handling Timer Control in Android

Tags: android, timer

I am using Android Timer for a game. I want to implement a countdown timer.

My requirement is to pause Timer on pressing home button when the activity goes into background. There is no such Timer Pause method.

How to handle the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this is on the `onPause()` method you saved the current time, then using the `OnResume()` create a new timer starting at the time you stored within the `onPause()` method.